# Dropdown populate ajax

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, populate

I have the following issue: When i select an element from a drop down i want to auto populate another drop down via ajax. the idea is that the subcategory(sub_type) doesn't load after selecting the "type".

```
HTML
<select id="type" name="type">
<option value="1">General</option>
<option value="2">Test</option>
</select>
<select id="sub_type" name="sub_type">
</select>


SCRIPT
    $("#type").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("ajax/add_subcathegory.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].id+ '">' + j[i].name+ '</option>';
          }
        });
    $("#sub_type").html(options);
    });
```

My ajax script returns:

```
[{id: 0, name: 'Mark'}, {id:1, name: 'Andy'}, {id:2, name: 'Richard'}]
```

But the subcathegory (secont select) isn`t loaded.

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are having. Can you restate your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that the Ajax success function is indeed called, change the function code to:

```
          var $subType = $("#sub_type");
          $subType.empty();
          $.each(j, function () {
            $subType.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", this.id).text(this.name));
          });
```

Your main problems currently are:

- the `html` function is called only once because it's outside of the sucess function.
- the elements in the Ajax data have the keys *id* and *name* and not *optionValue* and *optionDisplay*

**Update:**

The returned JSON is invalid. String have to be quoted with double quotes, not single quotes. As a result, the `getJSON()` call fails silently.

Comment: is the following correct? becouse it doesn`t work either   $("#type").change(function(){
$.getJSON("ajax/add_subcathegory.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){   
   var $subType = $("#sub_type");
          $.each(j, function () {
            $subType.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", this.id).text(this.name));
          });
    });
});

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" I guess you mean nothing happens. Please try to debug where it fails so we can better help you. Have a look at Firefox's Javascript console (or an equivalent console in your browser) to see whether a Javascript error occurs. If not, use Firebug, Fiddler or a similar tool to watch the network requests and shows as the Ajax request and the Ajax response. With Firebug, you can also set a breakpoint in your success function to see whether it is called at all.

Comment: I am using chrome so I can see the ajax response, and I have no errors when running your modified script

Comment: response : [{"id":"0","name":"Mark"},{"id":"1","name":"Andy"},{id:"2","name":"Richard"}] result: nothing happens

Comment: even this one : [{id:0,name:"Mark"},{id:1,name:"Andy"},{id:2,name:"Richard"}]

Comment: Please use a JSON validator like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate your JSON first. All keys have to be quoted but your examples have only 2 of 3 or none at all.

Comment: thank you so much, i was panaking. Thanks for the patience too :-D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you are assigning the html to #sub_type right after the ajax JSON call. You should assign it in the ajax callback function like this:

```
$("#type").change(function(){
  $.getJSON("ajax/add_subcathegory.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    $("#sub_type").html(options);
  });    
});
```

Comment: doesn`t work either :|. does the spaces in the ajax response count?

Comment: Are you sure that #sub_type is visible? Try to call $('#sub_type').html('<option>Anything</option>'); outside the ajax callback to see if it works (or even outside the onchange function).