# how to populating dropdown list on an basis of another, having 3 list and data from database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

how to populating drop down list on basis of parent one like MIT course ware
visit it you will understand .........
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091103/dropdown-populate-ajax

Comment: tnx but i did not understand the above one please any other  link