# Filter multiple dropdown on selected dropdown in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So i have queried three columns from my sql table in PHP, and am displaying it.

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{
  $NAME[] = "$row[NAME]";
  $CONTENT[] = "$row[CONTENT]";
  $SPECIFIC[] = "$row[SPECIFIC]";
}
```

With this i have created three dropdown, all these arrays have same length.

```
$NAME_unique=array_unique($NAME);
$CONTENT_unique=array_unique($CONTENT);
$SPECIFIC_unique=array_unique($SPECIFIC);
echo "<div><table class='SearchBox'>";
    echo "<thead></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
       echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>Name</td>";
          echo "<td><select>"
          echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
          foreach($NAME_unique as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
          endforeach;
          echo "</select></td>";        

          echo "<td>Content</td>";
          echo "<td><select>"
          echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
          foreach($CONTENT_unique as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
          endforeach;
          echo "</select></td>";        

          echo "<td>Specific</td>";
          echo "<td><select>"
          echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
          foreach($SPECIFIC_unique as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
          endforeach;
          echo "</select></td>";                                        
      echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Now what i want to do is create a filter that if i select a certain name: content and specifc are displayed accordingly. If i select content the specific is diplayed according. Three column look like this:

So my tables look like this:

```
NAME        CONTENT             SPECIFC

Gary        Rivers              Mississippi
Peter       Florida             Miami
Peter       Texas               Austin
Gary        Rivers              Hudson  
Gary        Lakes               Michigan
Sarah       Africa              Zimbabwe
Peter       Texas               Houston
Sarah       Asia                China
Sarah       Asia                Japan
```

What i want is by default all these should be populated, what i currently have.
But now if for NAME: Sarah is selected; it automatically changes the CONTENT to Asia, Africa and SPECIFC becomes Japan, China, Zimbabwe.
Same way if Peter selected; CONTENT is Texas, Florida and SPECIFIC becomes Houston, Austin, Miami. 
Or if in default i select CONTENT to be Rivers; SPECIFC needs to be Mississipi, Hudson.

Now i have experience doing 1 drop down other using Javascript, HTML; but never 2 dropdwon on 1. Can this be done in PHP. I have read online about using ajax but i have no experience with it and could not find a good example. How to do it just using PHP/Javascript/jquery?

Comment: In case you want it to happen immedeatly after changing any value of the dropdown you have to use javascript (jquery recommended)

Comment: I thin I had the same issue, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091103/dropdown-populate-ajax

Comment: not hard to research how to use multiple filter criteria in vanilla javascript or jQuery to only display filtered results. If you are wanting to do it in php would be normal form submit